# Why are vertices coordinates are always between -1 and 1 in 3D Models

Tags: c++, graphics-programming, sdl2

I'm writing my very first 3D rendering engine in C++ using SDL2, and I've been following this book that has multiple code examples that has 3D models with vertices that all have coordinates between -1 and 1. The problem is I can't wrap my head why is that exactly. I tried creating a cube on my engine with vertex coordinates positioned according to where I want the object to be ex: v1 is (300, 100, 10) but then when rotating the cube it goes all out the place. Can someone explain why this is happening

Comment: My personal experience says that vertices of 3d models are **not** always between -1 and 1. But all the examples from your book might have them in that area. We might be able to tell you what you are doing wrong when you showed us the code you wrote to create the cube and rotate it.

Comment: It sounds like your real question is "How can I stop my cube from going all out the place when rotating?". In addition to the code Philipp requested above, it would also help if you can capture some screenshots or an animation of the symptoms of the problem, so we all have the same idea of what "all out the place" means in this situation. Clear symptoms can help isolate the problem faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In graphics programming, we have the concept of multiple coordinate systems. Models that we create are typically made in model space (or local space if you prefer). When you make a model in e.g. blender, there is a coordinate system with an origin that all of the model's vertices are relative to. When we want to use those models in a game, we typically want to be able to move them, rotate them, and scale them so they appear in the correct location.

We accomplish this with translation, rotation, and scale matrices. Typically, we apply the scale, then the rotation, and then the translation. Together, these are called a world matrix. Multiplying a vertex in model space by its world matrix will move it into world space. From there, your view and projection matrices will convert it into screen space. This matrix multiplication is done in the shader typically.

In short, there shouldn't be an arbitrary limit on the coordinates of your models. Create your models around their own model origin and then position the model origin wherever you want in space.

The reason why your cube is going wacky is likely because the vertices are defined relative to the world origin and not to their own model origin. Your matrix is rotating the vertices around the world origin.